# How do I define a nested HashMap with an unknown nesting level?

Tags: rust

I want to traverse through a file tree and save the file and directory names in a nested `HashMap`. How do I define such a nested `HashMap`?

Something like this doesn't compile:

```rust
type NestedHashMap = HashMap<String, HashMap>;
```

It throws:

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected at least 2, found 0
 --> src/lib.rs:3:38
  |
3 | type NestedHashMap = HashMap<String, HashMap>;
  |                                      ^^^^^^^ expected at least 2 type arguments
```

Comment: There are functions and libraries for walking directories. Why do you need to store it in a map?

Comment: I'm using jwalk for parsing because of speed. The drawback of jwalk ist that I do not get the results in a manner and order which is suitable for the walk call like it is in Python. So I have to collect all the results first, build the nested hashmap and then return the results with an iterator.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the results as returned by jwalk?

Comment: The order the items are returned. I want to build a method like os.walk in Python, which returns all directories and files within a directory per iteration. But WalkDir::new(path) iterates immediately into subdirectories before the parsing of the current directory has finished.

Comment: What order does jwalk return the items in?

Comment: And is jwalk really faster than the walkdir crate? I have a hard time believing that walking directories is CPU-bound, which is the only thing rayon can help with.

Comment: jwalk is a lot faster. Especially on Windows file access is very slow if it is done in serial. Parallelization improves the performance a lot.

Comment: I did some crude benchmarking on my Linux box, and with hot caches I could indeed see a slight advantage for jwalk. With cold caches, they are mostly on par, but walkdir uses a lot less CPU overall. I understand that things are different on Windows, but for Linux it really doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: I did some benchmarks on my Linux desktop (Ryzen 5+SSD) and Windows 10 Laptop (i7+SSD). The results are mixed with some Python code and the comparison is between Python's os.walk and scandir-rs: https://github.com/brmmm3/scandir-rs
Results: On Linux scandir-rs is 2 times faster and on Windows 10 up to 17 times faster.
Due to lack of time I didn't compare Rusts WalkDir with jwalk, but I assume that the C-Code behind os.walk has comparable speed as WalkDir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust is a statically typed language, so you need to tell the compiler in advance the exact type of the elements in your `HashMap`. Since each entry can be either a file name or another `HashMap`, the easiest solution is to use an `enum` type:

```
enum Entry {
    File(String),
    Directory(HashMap<String, Entry>),
}
```

This allows you to model arbitrary nesting.